# Discord-бот прекращает воспроизведение музыки на определенной итерации

Tags: python, ubuntu, discord, discord.py, ffmpeg

Использую следующий код для воспроизведения музыки в голосовой канал дискорда:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

YDL_OPTIONS = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best', 
}

FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
    'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 
    'options': '-vn'
}

bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def get_source_url(url: str) -> str:
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        return ydl.extract_info(url, download=False).get('url')

@bot.slash_command(name='play')
async def __play(ctx, url: str) -> None:
    source = await get_source_url(url)
    vc = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))

    while vc.is_playing() or vc.is_paused():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await vc.disconnect()

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Принцип работы следующий:

1. Обработчик команды `/play` получает аргумент `url`, в виде ссылки на прямую трансляцию с YouTube: https://youtu.be/jfKfPfyJRdk *(или любое другое видео)*
2. Ссылка передается в функцию `get_source_url`, которая с помощью библиотеки `yt-dlp` возвращает прямую ссылку на звук из видео
3. Прямая ссылка передается через `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio` в программу `ffmpeg`, которая затем возвращает байты звука для передачи в голосовой канал дискорда через метод `vc.play`

---

### Проблема:

Захостил бота на виртуальном сервере хостинга [**aeza**](https://aeza.net/), ОС — `Ubuntu Server 22.04`. Установил командой `sudo apt install ffmpeg` программу `ffmpeg` версии `4.4.2`.

В первый день все отлично работало, но на следующий день бот стал стабильно прекращать воспроизведение музыки на одном и том же моменте в различных видео *(для каждого видео этот момент свой)*. **Перезапуск бота или сервера не помог.**

**Помогает только переустановка операционной системы, но также, всего на один день.**

### Конкретная проблема:

Я проверил выполнение каждой отдельной строки метода [`discord.VoiceClient.play`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/_modules/discord/voice_client.html#VoiceClient.play), включая все вызываемые внутри методы. Оказалось, что бот каждый раз зависает на одной и той же итерации цикла получения и пересылки байтов. А именно — на первой строке метода [`discord.FFmpegPCMAudio.read`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/_modules/discord/player.html#FFmpegPCMAudio.read), т.е. не получает данных от `ffmpeg` и бесконечно ждет.

---

### Источник проблемы:

Проблема не в конкретной `ffmpeg`:

- Я устаналивал также `ffmpeg` другой версии `5.1.2` и на ней проблема повторялась.

Проблема не в `Ubuntu Server`:

- Я менял ОС `Ubuntu Server` на `Debian 11` и там тоже самое

Проблема не в самом `Linux`:

- Когда я поставил те же ОС к себе на виртуалку, там все работало исправно с любой версией `ffmpeg`.

---

Значит, проблема на стороне хостинга? Попросил тех. поддержку поменять сам сервер и локацию расположения. Изменил со Швеции на Германию — тот же результат.

Если данные не приходят от `ffmpeg`, значит надо узнавать что не так в самой программе. Передаю при обращении аргумент `-loglevel debug`, показывающий максимально подробный отчет о работе программы — выводится все отладочная информация, но на "зависшей" итерации никаких ошибок "нет".

**Куда копать дальше?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Проблема решилась сама собой ¯\_(ツ)_/¯